# Is there any library for this error or something else?

Tags: database, php-5.4

```
 $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

i received this error on browser when I run the code.

Using $this when not in object context in `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\test.php`

What should i do for this .

Answer (score 3):

you should have this:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
        $app = Mage::app();
        Mage::helper('catalog/output');
```

Basically the $this->helper is calling the function that is contained inside the current template's block class. The Mage::helper is calling the function in the "God" class.

The $this->helper normally calls a function in the class Mage_Core_Block_Abstract which checks the layout for a helper and then simply calls the normal Mage::helper if it cannot find one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating a stand alone script.

so you can try below things to work

```
require_once("$Magento_Root_DIR/app/Mage.php"); // include Mage.php file 
$app = Mage::app(); //init Mage::app()
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output'); //calling helper class
```